# Good practice using NSURLConnection and its callbacks? Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsurlconnection

I don't have a current problem really, but rather a question that I can't seem to find a satisfying answer to.

What is good practice to use when handling callbacks and invokations of NSURLConnection in objective-c? Let's look at some examples.

Let's say I have 3 different ViewControllers, and I've created a class that does the network calls with NSURLConnection in order to obtain a JSON from some site. All 3 VC's will be doing different kinds of network calls. How would one go about doing this without having to repeat code or have the network handling all spread out? And what if I need to make more network calls depending on the result of a previous call?

I use the normal NSURLConnection delegates, such as `didReceiveResponse`, `didReceiveData`, `connectionDidFinishLoading` etc. So what I do is I store the statusCode in `didReceiveResponse` and in `connectionDidFinishLoading` I call a function I name `handleResponse` which checks the statusCode and if the statusCode states that the call was successful I translate the `NSData*` object that I've stored the data I received from `didReceiveData` delegate. This is all fine, but the data I translate I want to be sent to the correct viewController.

There are several options to do this:

1. I let the delegate for the NSURLConnection calls be the
   ViewController itself. This sucks, since I have to duplicate the
   NSURLConnection code in every VC I want to make a network call,
   obviously.
2. Or I could handle all the data in the Network class that performs
   the NSURLConnection calls. This sucks since I get logic code in a
   network class, and I don't really want that? This also requires that the Network Class knows about classes and data structures that it probably shouldn't. It's a network class and should not do anything but networking stuff.
3. My final approach, which I try for the first time now, is to let the
   ViewController tell the network class that it wants to make a
   NSURLConnection call, and sets a `NSNotification` message which the
   Network class should invoke in the `handleResponse` method I
   mentioned earlier. The Network class sends the data it received
   through that NSNotification and the logic for handling that data
   falls on the VC that asked for instead. To me this is most logical
   and feels like a somewhat good way of doing things.

The problem with solution 3 is that I have to have different Notification methods to handle different kinds of data, which could result in quite a few such methods. If different VC's also use the same kind of data handling as another NSNotification method, then I have to duplicate that code as well. I'm also fairly new to using NSNotification in general and not very knowledgeable about its drawbacks.

Final question, let's say I want to make 4 different NSURLConnection calls, one after the other has been confirmed finished and successful. How would you go about that? I've done this a few times, but it ends up as a counter in the form of an enum to keep track of which network call was just made and which one should be next, which results in switch-statements executing certain code depending on which was just performed. I'm thinking about maybe implementing some sort of queue which goes through all calls in a sequence instead.

I appreciate any kind of input!

Comment: Did you take a look at AFNetworking 2.0 ?

Comment: While this isn't a direct answer to your question, hence the comment, why aren't you using `NSURLSession`, which is the successor to `NSURLConnection`? Are you supporting iOS < 7?

Comment: I haven't checked AFNetworking or NSURLSession out, didn't know about them but thanks, will check both out!

Comment: You don't need a library for that kind of stuff. Your third approach is the best, however, I would use delegation instead of notifications. To avoid fat view controllers I recommend that you create your network class which delegates the data to a converter which converts the data into objects and passes those objects to your view controller which in turn updates its views. And as Gregory told you I would use NSURLSession.

Comment: The "4 downloads after another" could be done using a state machine. Or you use the same instance for downloading those 4 downloads and set NSURLSession's maxConnectionsPerHost (or so) to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most if not all of these problems are solved by AFNetworking. Specially the problems concerning having to duplicate requests or connections.

For the final question, for example you can do it with blocks AFNetworking provides such a structure, so you can specifically coordinate multiple calls.

**[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)**

There are a lot of tutorials out there and the brief documentation of the library github site provides short, concise and easy to understand examples. Getting to use it takes a few minutes.

Comment: I'm going to set this as the correct answer. I haven't looked at AFNetworking, didn't know about it at all. Thanks a lot, will check this out. Looks to be exactly what I'm asking for.